# Street Address Format regex to remove characters from the string

Tags: regex

I have street address and I want to replace the street direction with comma blank string.

I would like convert street address like following -

```
Example Format : Street1, Street2, State, City, ZipCode

Example String1 : "5TH AVE, , NY, New York, "
i want result : "5TH AVE, NY, New York"

Example String1 : ", , NY, New York, "
i want result : "NY, New York"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the multiline and global flags, `/(?<!\w\d), |, (?=$)/gm` seems to do the trick!

The first half matches any `,<space>` that is *not* preceded by any word character or digit, and the second half matches any `,<space>` that is followed by the end of the line.

https://regex101.com/r/OVLfQh/1

Comment: So Good Thank you